# How to echo json object properties in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

## JSON data

```
"orders":[  
     "billing_details":{  
        "company":"Test Company",
        "firstname":"Munadil",
        "postcode":"5000",
        "street":"Dhaka, Bangladesh",
        "email":"munadil98@gmail.com",
        "lastname":"Fahad",
        "ph_number":"880191111111",
        "city":"Dhaka",
        "state":"Mirpur",
        "country_code":"BN",
        "user_id":16003511,
        "salutation":null
     }]
```

## In PHP

```
$json_output = json_decode($response);
foreach ( $json_output->orders as $orders ){
foreach ($orders->billing_details as $billing_details) {echo "<b>Name:</b><br>".$billing_details->firstname." ".$billing_details->lastname."<br>";}
}
```

But I am getting below error message,

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ....

How can I echo data inside "billing_details" object under array "orders" ?

Comment: `billing_details` is a key inside an array. Try `"orders":[{...}]`

Comment: where did you declare the variable $orders?

Comment: That is invalid JSON.

Comment: @mike.k Please mention exact syntax to echo values inside billing_details

Comment: @MunadilFahad first please correct your json, bcoz the one you have shown above is invalid!

Comment: since this question has been marked as a duplicate here is a workaround `$json = json_decode(rtrim(substr($response, strpos($response, '{')), ']'));`

Comment: @victor, please check my revised post above, $orders was defined in parent foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$json_output = json_decode($response);

foreach ($json_output['orders'] as $billing_details) {
echo "<b>Name:</b><br>$billing_details['firstname'] $billing_details['lastname']<br>";}
```

Comment: tell us this will work.

Comment: @julekgwa Thanks i have updated answer

Comment: this won't work.

Comment: i dont understand why?

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: yes i have .it works

Comment: I wonder how you have tested, as I'm getting tons of errors using your code.

Comment: i think there is some mistake in json

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`$json_output = json_decode($response['orders']);`

`echo $json_output;`

Comment: How do you echo an array? Btw, `$response` is a string at this point so `$response['orders']` will fail.

Comment: Problem solved. Actually, I found that some "orders" array don't have "billing_details" object. This was the reason of returning error. For the "orders" array which have "billing_details" object found ok. So, I get rid of showing error message by if else condition. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: Your problem solved.Thats great!!